# oracle procedure - getting compile warnings

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I've checked the previous similar questions, none seem to match my problem.
After compiling the code, I get "Warning: execution completed with warning"  I tried to run `Show errors;`, but got nothing.  I then ran the code

Updated - 2014-07-15 9:54 AM est.

```
execute buy_ball('Soccer Ball', 1);
```

And I get the following errors;

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
execute buy_ball('Soccer Ball', 1);
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object SYSMAN.BUY_BALL is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550.  00000 - "line%s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:  Usually a PL/SQL compilation Error
```

Code is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE buy_ball(aProductnm in VARCHAR2, 
                                 aNumber in number)

AS
qtyoh NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT quantityonhand 
INTO qtyoh 
FROM inventory 
WHERE productname = aProductnm;

IF qtyoh > 0 
THEN
UPDATE inventory 
SET quantityonhand = (qtyoh – aNumber) 
WHERE Productname = aProductnm;

INSERT INTO purchase_record (orderdate, 
                             orderstatus, 
                             quantitypurchase, 
                             productname)
VALUES (sysdate, 
        'Soccer Ball purchased', 
        aNumber, 
        aProductnm);
ELSE
INSERT INTO purchase_record (orderdate, 
                           orderstatus, 
                           quantitypurchase, 
                           productname)
VALUES (sysdate, 
        'Out of Stock', 
        aNumber, 
        aProductnm);
END IF;

COMMIT;
END;
```

show error runs but shows nothing.  Only when I execute the command per the execute command above do I get the error.

Comment: Yes I did mean that to be an equals sign.  However I have tried your updated code, and I still get the exact same errors.

Answer (score 1):

When declaring parameters and function return types,do not include precisions or scales.You can limit it only by declaring the variable first then passing it as the argument to the function.

Comment: Thanks - I removed all precisions and scales, however I still get the exact same error.  Any other suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: what error do you get when compiling the procedure? recompile the proc and use show error.

Comment: @Nitish - The errors are exactly as described in my original post.  When compiling I get the Warning, and the errors only when I execute.

Answer (score 0):

use this version---

```
create or replace
procedure buy_ball(aProductnm  in Varchar2, aNumber  in number)
AS
qtyoh number(5) ;
Begin
select quantityonhand into qtyoh from inventory where productname = aProductnm;
if qtyoh > 0 then
  update inventory set quantityonhand = (qtyoh - aNumber) where Productname - aProductnm;
  insert into purchase_record (orderdate, orderstatus, quantitypurchase, productname)
  values
  (sysdate, 'Soccer Ball Purchased', aNumber, aProductnm);

else
   insert into purchase_record (orderdate, orderstatus, quantitypurchase, productname)
   values
   (sysdate, 'Out of Stock', aNumber, aProductnm);
end if;
commit;
end;
```

I have assumed that in the below mentioned statement you meant'=' rather than '-' --->

select quantityonhand into qtyoh from inventory where productname - aProductnm;

Comment: Thanks - Yes I did mean that to be an equals sign.  However I have tried your updated code, and I still get the exact same errors.

Comment: What are those exact same errors that you get when you compile the procedure?

Comment: as far as your code is concerned -- there are some issues like a) declare statement after create or replace statement, declare is generally used with anonymous block.                                   b) select statement before begin, until it's not cursor don't use it outside begin.                                                        c)while mentioning parameters in stored procedure, you just need to provide the data-type and not the size of the data type you are using

Comment: you are getting error with my version as because of update statement    replace this statement with the update statement current written in my version.                                                              update inventory set quantityonhand = (qtyoh - aNumber) where Productname = aProductnm;

Comment: if after replacing this you are still getting error, please attach the log.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure did not compile and hence your were getting errors, you have to use  conditional operators such as `%`, `=`, `IN` etc. in where condition as you were using assignment operators.

Try with the following code,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE buy_ball (aProductnm   IN VARCHAR2,
                                      aNumber      IN NUMBER)
AS
   qtyoh   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT quantityonhand
     INTO qtyoh
     FROM inventory
    WHERE productname = aProductnm;

   IF qtyoh > 0
   THEN
      UPDATE inventory
         SET quantityonhand = (qtyoh - aNumber)
       WHERE Productname = aProductnm;

      INSERT INTO purchase_record (orderdate,
                                   orderstatus,
                                   quantitypurchase,
                                   productname)
           VALUES (SYSDATE,
                   'Soccer Ball Purchased',
                   aNumber,
                   aProductnm);
   ELSE
      INSERT INTO purchase_record (orderdate,
                                   orderstatus,
                                   quantitypurchase,
                                   productname)
           VALUES (SYSDATE,
                   'Out of Stock',
                   aNumber,
                   aProductnm);
   END IF;

   COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks - however - running the code above produces the exact same warning and errors upon execut.

Comment: @Drew You mean to say you are getting exactly same errors you have mentioned in your question?

Comment: yes as per my first post.  I'm sure it's something easy to overlook...the code itself is straight forward and the individual commands are correct. I've even tried re-starting the service...

Comment: @Drew Add `show_errors` line and paste in your question by editing.

Comment: @Drew Slightly off topic though, it is not at all a good idea to create database objects in `SYSMAN` schema. Always create your objects a schema which is not database's schema such as `SYS`,`SYSTEM`,`SYSMAN` etc.

Comment: @Drew From where have you been trying to execute `execute buy_ball('Soccer Ball', 1);`? From `SQL Plus`, `TOAD`, `SQLDeveloper` etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments and assistance.  I have managed to get the code to work properly, and I am enclosing the final version here. (10 hours of changing a space here or there adding cursors and removing them etc.  you all know how that goes!)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE BUY_BALL (I_Productnm VARCHAR2, I_Number NUMBER)                
AS
  qtyoh NUMBER(10,0);
BEGIN
SELECT quantityonhand
INTO qtyoh
    FROM inventory
    WHERE productname = I_Productnm;
IF qtyoh > 0 THEN
UPDATE inventory 
SET quantityonhand = qtyoh - I_Number
WHERE Productname = I_Productnm;
INSERT INTO purchase_record (orderdate,
                             orderstatus,
                             quantitypurchase,
                             productname)
VALUES (sysdate,
        'Soccer Ball purchased',
        I_Number,
        I_Productnm);
ELSE
INSERT INTO purchase_record (orderdate,
                           orderstatus,
                           quantitypurchase,
                           productname)
VALUES (sysdate,
        'Out of Stock',
        I_Number,
        I_Productnm);
END IF;
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

The one issue that I think I found was that I saw a post about using capital letters for the procedure name - it was a known bug in 2012, and as I'm using Oracle 11g, I suspect it may still exist for my version.  When I changed that, the procedure compiled cleanly and executed properly.
Thanks again!